# ArrayList is showing empty after getting data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing firebase in my app.  Please refer the below image as a reference to my database.

[image: The SLC Structure]

I have an array of SLC names and I need to generate an arrayList of SLC keys. So I am trying to create an arrayList of  specific SLC keys. Please see the below code once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    Query query = ref.child(pref.getString("groupSelectedDCU", "") + "/" + "DeviceList")
                     .orderByChild("name")
                     .equalTo(arr.get(i));
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Log.d("arrID", child.getKey() + "");
                arrID.add(child.getKey());
            }

            Log.d("arrID", Arrays.toString(arrID.toArray()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
}
Log.d("arrID", Arrays.toString(arrID.toArray()));
```

Here I am trying to add all the SLC keys into the `arrID` arraylist. But while accessing the arrayList, it returns an empty array. Am I missing something or do I have to add any more listeners? Need your help.

Comment: Isn't firebase Json based?

Comment: @LunarWatcher: yes, it is

Comment: Do you parse it correctly?

Comment: @LunarWatcher: Yes parsing is correct. But the arrayList is getting filled after sometimes ,, like I am missing some listener

Comment: Are you expecting arrID to be populated by the time that log statement is executed immediately after adding listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) works. The provided [`ValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) methods will be called *asynchronously* in the background, when the query response finally arrives from the network. As such, when this last statement runs (after the *for loop*):

```
...
Log.d("arrID", Arrays.toString(arrID.toArray()));
```

the `arrID` will *still* be empty since none of the `onDataChange` methods has been called yet.

**Alternative solution**. If you need to wait until *all* queries are done, try this instead:

```
List<String> arrID = ArrayList<String>();
int remainingQueries = arr.size(); 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    Query query = ...
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("arrID", child.getKey() + "");
                arrID.add(child.getKey());
            }
            Log.d("arrID", Arrays.toString(arrID.toArray()));
            if (--remainingQueries == 0) onQueriesDone(arrID);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });
}
```

which will call this method when done:

```
private void onQueriesDone(List<String> arrID) {
    Log.d("arrID", Arrays.toString(arrID.toArray()));
}
```

In particular, we don't need *synchronization locks* to access the shared counter `remainingQueries` since all Firebase callbacks are triggered on the main thread.